# Position image in bottom right of shape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to create something that looks like this:

[image]

However, it currently comes out like this (zoomed out a bit):

[image]

I can't figure out how to put the profile picture in the bottom right.

Here's my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/circle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bg"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the `bg` drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">

            <solid android:color="#4a9ef7"/>
            <size android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/circle"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bg"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/avatar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bg"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bg"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

Here alignRight and alignBottom will align the imageview to the bottom right of your background. Also you can avoid layerlist and use only shape drawable for background.

Answer (score 1):

@user4368069 FYI:

**`android:layout_alignParentRight`**:If true, makes the right edge of this view match the right edge of the parent. Accommodates right margin.

**`android:layout_alignParentBottom`**:If true, makes the bottom edge of this view match the bottom edge of the parent. Accommodates bottom margin.

Both are

> boolean value, either "true" or "false"

And set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in your Imageview
.
For better information please read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`.

And set the avatar `ImageView` with `gravity="right|bottom"`.